# render :json does not accept options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I'd love to use `render :json` but it seems its not as flexible.  Whats the right way to do this?

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @things }

  #This is great
  format.json { render :text => @things.to_json(:include => :photos) }

  #This doesn't include photos
  format.json { render :json => @things, :include => :photos }
end
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've done something similar with `render :json`.  This is what worked for me:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @things.to_json(:include => { :photos => { :only => [:id, :url] } }) }
end
```

Answer (score 35):

I guess this article can be useful for you - [Rails to_json or as_json?](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/) by Jonathan Julian.

The main thought is that you should avoid using to_json in controllers. It is much more flexible to define as_json method in your model.

For instance:

In your Thing model

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(:include => :photos)
end
```

And then you can write in your controller just

```
render :json => @things
```

Comment: Might want to do `super(options.merge(:include => :photos))` to preserve other possible passed-in options.  You would still override any `:include` options, though... the logic for merging values for that key would get a bit more involved.

Comment: Using `super options.reverse_merge :include => :photos` would allow you to override the "default" :include.  (See [Hash#reverse_merge](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-reverse_merge))

Answer (score 3):

Managing complex hashes in your controllers gets ugly fast.

With Rails 3, you can use ActiveModel::Serializer. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html

If you're doing anything non-trivial, see 
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers. I recommend creating separate serializer classes to avoid cluttering your models and make tests easier.

```
class ThingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :photos
  attributes :name, :whatever
end

# ThingsController
def index
  render :json => @things
end

# test it out
thing = Thing.new :name => "bob"
ThingSerializer.new(thing, nil).to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

```
format.json { render @things.to_json(:include => :photos) }
```

Answer (score 1):

in case of array what I done is

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json {render :json => {:medias => @medias.to_json, :total => 13000, :time => 0.0001 }}
end
```