# How to call a Rails method with the help of JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to call a Rails method from a JavaScript method using AJAX. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't exactly "call" a Rails method from the front end. What you can do is have a controller method that renders JSON, and request the URL that routes to that controller method.

Returning JSON is fairly straightforward; you might use something like the syntax in this post:
[render :json does not accept options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611931/render-json-does-not-accept-options)

Answer (score -1):

- [Prototype AJAX documentation](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request)
- [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)