# Making a method accessible to views, controller and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm on Rails 3.0. For a model's `updated_at` column, I need to output that as a user friendly format in JSON, so instead of seeing this `2011-09-14T22:01:32Z` as the value, I would like to show `less than a minute ago` (or whatever user-friendly message I decide) for `updated_at`. I wrote a method that returns the output in the user-friendly format and now needs the functionality to be available in views, controller and model. What's the best way to do this so it isn't convoluted or bad practice.

**EDIT** Per answer from @klochner, here's what my `date.rb` looks like but now it throws `date.rb:21:in`format': wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) (ArgumentError)`

```
include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def friendly
    format
  end
end

class Date
  def friendly
    format
  end
end

class Time
  def friendly
    format
  end
end

def format
  if self.today?
    format_time = ...
  elsif (self < Time.now.beginning_of_day) and (self > Time.now.yesterday.beginning_of_day)
    format_time = ...
  else
    format_time = ...
  end
end
```

@klochner suggestion changing `format` to `format_helper` works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonkeyPatch the `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` class, here's what I do (I put this in `config/initializers/date.rb`)

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def mdy
    self.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  end
end
class Date
  def mdy
    self.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  end
end
class Time
  def mdy
    self.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
  end
end
```

Then for any date object (or date field in an AR model), you can call `mdy()`:

```
 > Time.now.mdy
 => "09/14/2011" 
> User.first.created_at.mdy
 => "02/27/2009" 
> Date.today.mdy
 => "09/14/2011"
```

For json, you probably want to write an `as_json` method for the model that you're rendering.  See this related answer:
[render :json does not accept options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611931/render-json-does-not-accept-options)

Comment: Good stuff, I was able to get the basics working, now the question is how to include this in JSON, I could create custom methods and include them using `:methods` in the JSON call but I prefer something more elegant if possible. Sorry I can't vote up for your answer yet since I don't have enough reputation points, if you vote my question up, it might help me to vote your answer up :)

Comment: i don't understand why you can't include this in JSON - just use the instance method, it should be available everywhere.

Comment: What would be the syntax for the JSON call? Also, I ran into a new issue, `rails console` now throws a `wrong number of arguments (2 for 0) error in 'format' for `date.rb'. I have updated my question with the details of `format` method.

Comment: you can fix the argument error by renaming format to format_helper

Comment: Sorry @klochner, I still don't have enough points to up vote your answer but I can now mark it as an answer. Yes, I just got 15 points and up vote your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding custom methods for the models I want included in the JSON output. Your suggestion is a good one though I don't see how I can `:include :only` for something like `comment.updated_at.friendly`. I think I can only `:include :only => [:updated_at, ...]`.