# Fetch all records with associations in RoR 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in RoR 3 and I am experiencing a problem.
I have a class `User` like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :login, :password, :rank, :sa_id, 
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :company
end
```

When in my controller I get first user (for example) `User.first` I can access to `User.first.role`

Is it possible to fetch all users including the belongs_to objects ?
Like the result would be all the users and in each user an object of type role and an object of type company?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but you can eager load the associations so only 1 request is sent to the database (actually 3, one for the users, one for the roles, and one for the companies)

```
>> users = User.includes(:role, :company)
>> users.each do |user|
     puts user.role
     puts user.company
   end
```

UPDATE: to render json, use

```
respond_with(@user) do |format|
  format.json { render json: @user.to_json(methods: [:company, :role] }
end
```

Comment: Not so sure that .includes was necessary. is it ?

Comment: it is if you want to eager load. if you don't do that, you'll have to query the database each time you access `user.role` and `user.company`

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't make any change in the returned result. I still only have my users. User.includes(:role, :company) returns only the users list and the loop doesn't change anything.

Comment: so it appears I really didn't get your question.  It would help if you show some sort of results that you are expecting.

Comment: I expect somthing like [{
    "user": {
        "company_id": 1,
        "login": "mylogin",
        "password": "mypassword",
        "role_id": 1,
    },
    "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "QuimeO",
    },
    "role": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "This is my role",
    }
},
{
    "user": {
        "company_id": 1,
        "login": "mylogin",
        "password": "mypassword",
        "role_id": 1,
    },
    "company": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "QuimeO",
    },
    "role": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "This is my role",
    }
}]

Comment: so are you expecting a hash or json?

Comment: I am expecting a json (I use repond_to :json and use respond_with user after the query

Comment: ok just a reminder that you should've mentioned that in your question. updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was the query, not the rendering. Thanks it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you used scaffolding, there should be also a generated `index` method inside you UsersController.

There you should see something like this:

```
@users = User.all
```

This fetches all User objects from database.

Now you can iterate over those Users and access the `role` field like you did before.

But: This uses lazy loading. Means: For every accessed `role` it will execute a separate query. To fix this use "eager loading" (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations):

```
@users = User.includes(:role)
```

This will fetch all Users with it's associated role in one query

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not seem to work. I My index is users = User.includes(:role)
    users.each do |user|
      puts user.role
    end
    respond_with users
I am using respond_to  :json (it that matters).

Comment: Okay, your question is about `render json` and not about the query itself. For including things within the json output, things are almost the same: Use `include`. Look here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/612475/1321564