# add a local variable to a respond_to render view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, respond-to

I currently have the following code and it works fine:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :show, status: :ok }
end
```

I believe `:show` is referring to a jbuilder view.

However, if I wanted to add a local variable to the json render, how would I do that?

I've tried the following but it hasn't worked.

```
auth = true
format.json { render :show, :include => auth, status: :ok }
```

and I've also tried

```
auth = true
format.json { render :show.include(auth), status: ok }
```

From what I found at [render :json does not accept options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611931/render-json-does-not-accept-options)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one

```
format.json { render :show, locals:{auth: auth}, status: :ok }
```

now you have a variable auth in your show view